# (Modal) Component in Loop

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am using the [modal component](https://kouts.github.io/ractive-modal/) for Ractive.js and some self written components as well.

They all work like a charm until I want to use them inside a loop:

```
{{# buildingTypes:index}}
    <button type="button" class="button full xs" on-click="@this.set('open_modal', true)">choose</button>

    {{#if index == 0}}
        <modal title="My first modal" basedon="{{open_modal}}">
            <p>Hello World!</p>
        </modal>
    {{/if}}
{{/buildingTypes}}
```

If I move the `<modal>` outside of the loop the modal works again.
My assumption now is, that the component is unknown inside the loop.

How can I get the component to work inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I got it working now.

For the modal component I needed to enbale the option `live`: *Controls whether the modal renders dynamically or stays hidden in the DOM*.

For my custom components I needed to update my Ractive instance `ractive.update('buildingTypes')`.